# How to run encryption commands on linux without shell history logging

Tags: linux, bash, shell, encryption, command-history

I want to encrypt something without logging any part of the shell command to bash history.  I don't want the password or any filenames or the command to appear in the shell history. How to do it using AES 256 with SHA2? (I believe this is the most secret configuration today, is it?)

Comment: This is actually 2 questions.  You might consider opening another question for "the most secret configuration today".

Comment: Prefix your command with one space.

Comment: @Cyrus, true, should mention that works only with `bash`, and also depends on configuration

Comment: @RobertL: That is correct. Variable `HISTCONTROL` should contain keyword `ignorespace`.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/is-there-any-way-to-keep-a-command-from-being-added-to-your-history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ unset HISTFILE
$ cat something | openssl enc -e -aes256 > encrypted-something
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
```

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: `something` here is just the filename — you never said that the filename was sensitive.

Comment: You should know that `unset`ting the `HISTFILE` variable will not save *any* of the history list to the file, even those commands before `HISTFILE` was `unset`.  `bash` has an in memory "history list" that gets written to the `HISTFILE` when `bash` exits.

Comment: Can start the command line with a space as a way of not entering into the in-memory history list.

Comment: @BowlOfRed, that depends on `HISTCONTROL`/`HISTIGNORE`

Comment: @BowlOfRed Good point.  Note it works *only* in `bash` and depends on configuration of `bash` with environment variables as per @ilkkachu.  Usually default `bash` configuration supports this usage.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to turn off history *temporarily* is to start a subshell with the `HISTSIZE` *environment variable* set to `0`:

```
HISTSIZE=0 $0
type your commands here
<ctrl-D>
```

*History logging in your original login shell remains **unaffected** after exiting the subshell.*

The `$0` ensures that you start the same shell that you're using. You could replace `$0` with the path to any shell, for example: `/bin/sh`.

This works with most common shells including `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `dash`.  I think this is a POSIX standard.

You can also type `exit` to exit the subshell.

### Example

```
$ true 1
$ true 2
$ HISTSIZE=0 $0
$ true 3
$ true 4
$ exit
$ history 4
500  true 1
501  true 2
502  HISTSIZE=0 $0
503  history 4
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file names in the command line bother you, you can read them from the terminal:

```
read infile; read outfile; cat $infile | openssl enc -e -aes256 > $outfile;
```